# Difference between HSV and HSV_FULL in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am not able to get proper information regarding the difference between HSV and HSV_FULL in OpenCV. What is the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE (22/Jun/2023)** : This answer is plain wrong. Please check answer by Minsoo and the comments in it for the right answer.
(Unfortunately, SoF doesn't allow me to delete an accepted answer)

---

- For HSV, **range of Hue is 0-180.**
- For HSV_FULL, **range of Hue is 0-360.**

Comment: Any other difference other than that? which is better hsv or hsv_full?

Comment: I don't know if any difference. Also it is just scaling. Some tools use 0-180 range, while some tools use 0-360. I don't think if one is better than the other. Actually I always use the first one and I haven't faced any problem yet.

Comment: The main reason is you get better accuracy when working with integers on the price bigger memory consuption. 0-180 can be stored in `uint8`, for 0-360 you need `uint16` to avoid overflow.

Comment: As far as I can see this is wrong and `HSV_FULL` uses the full Byte i.e. 0..255 while `HSV` uses degree in scope 0°..180°.

Comment: This answer was wrong when it was posted. I went back to a random commit in January 2011, 3 years before this was posted. The code logic where the range for the H channel is determined is identical to what it is now (though the new code looks a bit cleaner). Back then the code was: `int hrange = depth == CV_32F ? 360 : code == CV_BGR2HSV || code == CV_RGB2HSV || code == CV_BGR2HLS || code == CV_RGB2HLS ? 180 : 255;` That is, for integer images, the range is either 180 or 255 depending on whether `_FULL` is selected or not. For floating-point images the range is always 360.

Comment: CrisLuengo, you are correct. My answer is wrong. As you said, I should have double-checked it.

Don't know who else, but definitely the first person who got misled was myself as I have been using BGR2HSV until today with this wrong concept in my mind. Thank you and  @Minsoo for the right answer.

I didn't answer in SoF to mislead. I simply love to share my knowledge with the community and gain more in return. And I definitely try not to post something which I am not sure. Unfortunately, I am not always correct and I try to correct if proven otherwise.
 
So I will delete this post.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't delete "accepted answer". 
@shreyas, could you please accept the other answer as the right one?

Comment: We’re all here to learn. I just re-read my words and they sounded harsher than I intended. Sorry. I deleted that comment. —— I forgot that accepted answers can’t be deleted. OP hasn’t been seen in 7 years, so they’re not going to change the check mark, unfortunately. Anyway, thanks for adding the notice. 

Comment: No problem. I only considered it as a reminder to be more careful, in my learning as well as sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why Abid's answer is chosen still. Maybe the information was correct, but seems like it is not correct anymore.
The correct answer as of June in 2023, the `HSV_FULL` has hue range of 0-255, which is a full byte.
Also stated in the official documentation of openCV. [Color Space Conversions](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#:%7E:text=convert%20RGB/BGR%20to%20HLS%20(hue%20lightness%20saturation)%20with%20H%20range%200..255%20if%208%20bit%20image).

The correct answer is:

- [For HSV, range of Hue is 0-180.](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#:%7E:text=with%20H%20range%200..180%20if%208%20bit%20image%2C,-color%20conversions) (degrees)
- [For HSV_FULL, range of Hue is 0-255.](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#:%7E:text=convert%20RGB/BGR%20to%20HLS%20(hue%20lightness%20saturation)%20with%20H%20range%200..255%20if%208%20bit%20image) (full byte)

Comment: Abid's answer has always been wrong. This  answer is right for integer-valued images. For floating-point images the range is always 0-360, the same for `HSV` and `HSV_FULL`.